# JQuery autocomplete appears behind JQuery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a JQuery autocomplete search box which when displaying the search results in the dropdown window appears behind a JQuery dropdown menu directly below it (see image). I have tried increasing the `z-index` value of everything I can find in the CSS for the autocomplete search but it still doesn't fix the problem. What else should I be trying?

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/tonyyeb/LKDBh/18/

[image: my error]

Comment: Is it the jQuery UI menu?

Comment: The menu was obtained from here a while ago (I'm not using the latest version) http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

Comment: It is difficult to answer without looking at the "generated" markup. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Or at least if you can provide a link to your website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's contributions. I have since found a solution given to me by a forum user:

> The autocomplete wrapper is being given a z-index of 1 by the jQuery library (hard-coded), >whereas the menu (via CSS) has a z-index of 100; easiest solution is to use -

`.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index: 100 !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a website recently and I've fixed this with the following method:

Make sure that you position both elements absolute OR relative (z-index only works when you use the 'position' css element. So you should either use position: absolute; or postion: relative;. That totally depends on your code/css. When you don't use the position element right now, you should probably use the position: relative; element since the position:absolute;  element will position the referring element absolutely which will probably screw up your layout).

Then make sure you give the dropdown a z-index which is lower then the z-index for the menu.

Example

```
.search-dropdown{
  position: relative; or position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.jquery-menu{
  position: relative; or position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. Where you say `position: relative; or position: absolute;` which one should be which?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but it still isn't working. I've added a fiddle to show it not working if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Now, you've added

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

to .ui-widget.

Remove it there and add it directly to the dropdown's css which appears when you enter something in the input field (Chrome/Firefox: Right Click on the dropdown and inspect element to see its class/ID).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried that, I've added it in various places (not all at the same time) but it still doesn't work. Can you see my Fiddle and see if you can get it to work?

Answer (score -1):

A few months ago I had a similar problem, and searched the web.

The solution was in the CSS styling.

I added an inline class (ui-front) to the element that holds the autocomplete input element.

Not sure it will solve your problem, but it's an easy experiment.

Best of luck!

Comment: generic answer, you are not explaining what style you added to fix the issue

Answer (score -1):

Question has been posted long time ago. Still, i also have a solution that works and not listed till now .
just add this on top of your page and problem should be solved.

.pac-container { position: absolute; cursor: default;z-index:3000 !important;}